# RAG LLM returning incorrect/unexpected search results

Tags: large-language-model, chromadb

I've loaded a student information dataset (name, age, division, hobbies) into a vector database with all features combined in a single textual column. When I query my RAG application for information about specific students, it sometimes:

Returns incorrect informationm or
Says "No data is available" when I know relevant information exists.

I'm wondering if adding an index to the vector database on the "student name" column and using that index during queries could improve accuracy and reliability. But I could not find any reference for such piece of code; Can you please provide some suggestions?

Code used for embedder

```
from langchain_custom_embedders import CustomChromaEmbedder
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter, RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_community.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader

import PyPDF2

textFilepath = "./student.txt"

loader = TextLoader(textFilepath)
documents = loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=2000, chunk_overlap=100)
chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
# embedding_function = CustomChromaEmbedder()
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name='sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2',
                                   model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})

db = Chroma.from_documents(documents=chunks, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory="./chromadb_student")
db.persist()
```

Comment: Can you try db.get() after your persist 
see if you get any data or not

Comment: Data is getting stored in the DB, except the similarity search does not work for specific attributes.